# how to exit from swipl to bash?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

```
stav> swipl
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 8.0.3)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?-
```

The only way I found is to run `cntr+c` multiple times + `exit` + enter.

is there a simple way to exit?

Comment: Of interest: SWI-Prolog [Overview](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=overview) - This starts at the very basics, including halt.

Comment: Interestingly, `swipl` doesn't "suspend process" when CTRL-Z is entered. Survivable in the age of windowing systems, but not nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+D` or `halt.`.

Interactive programs that read user input typically exit when you indicate that no more input is coming. `Ctrl+D` instructs the shell to tell the program that the `EOF` (end of file) has been reached, causing the program to exit.

This works with virtually all REPLs (Python, NodeJS, Ruby, ...) and many other programs. One random example: Run `md5sum` on the command line and type in some text. When you're done, press `Ctrl+D` and see the MD5 hash of the text you entered.

There is another Prolog-specific way to exit, which is the `halt` predicate (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=halt/0). Takes longer to type, but allows you to exit programmatically.